# Count how many identical elements in 2 arrays occur

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have a form and as a result of that form I have two arrays - one for personA's details and one for personB's details. One part of the form is a bunch of checkboxes of dates - the dates are a fixed price, but booking for two on the same date is a reduced price.

What I want to do is compare personA's array with personB's array and for any duplicates issue a reduced rate.

The rate will be calculated into two variables - total full price dates (in £s) and total reduced price dates (in £s).

Here is my code so far (this occurs on the checkboxes onclick):

```
function processDates(){
    var contentsA, valsA = [], dates_A =  document.forms['registerForm']['personADates[]'];
    for(var iA=0,elmA;elmA = dates_A[iA];iA++) {
        if(elmA.checked) {
            valsA.push(elmA.value);
        }
    }
    contentsA = valsA.join(', ');

    var contentsB, valsB = [], dates_B =  document.forms['registerForm']['personBDates[]'];
    for(var iB=0,elmB;elmB = dates_B[iB];iB++) {
        if(elmB.checked) {
            valsB.push(elmB.value);
        }
    }
    contentsB = valsB.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Just to be safe here, I noticed you said booking. Assuming this isn't an academic project, you need to *ensure* that validation takes place on the server-side. If you trust javascript as the authoritative input, I'll come over to your website and give myself whatever rate I want.

Comment: no it's not academic. The rate is calculated server side, but I need display the total price to them on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an array you could use an object (warning... untested code):

```
function processDates(){
    var valsA = {}, dates_A =  document.forms['registerForm']['personADates[]'];
    for(var iA=0,elmA;elmA = dates_A[iA];iA++) {
        if(elmA.checked) {
            valsA[elmA.value] = 1;  // Store values
        }
    }

    var samedate = [];
    var dates_B = document.forms['registerForm']['personBDates[]'];
    for(var iB=0,elmB;elmB = dates_B[iB];iB++) {
        if(elmB.checked) {
            if (valsB[elmB.value])
            {
                // Here we found a date that's present in both
                samedate.push(elmB.value);
            }
        }
    }
    // Here samedate is a list of all dates listed in both A and B
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- With my own http://phrogz.net/JS/ArraySetMath.js you could do:

  ```
  // If the original order of the elements is not important
  var common = array1.intersect( array2 );

  // If the original order of the elements is important
  var common = array1.unsortedIntersect( array2 );
  ```
- With the larger [JS.Set](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/set.html) you could do:

  ```
  // If the original order of the elements is not important
  var common = (new JS.SortedSet(array1)).intersect(new JS.SortedSet(array2));

  // If the original order of the elements is important
  var common = (new JS.Set(array1)).intersect(new JS.Set(array2));
  ```

It is not clear to me what the values in your arrays actually are; are these dates entered by the user in plain text? If so, you'll want to ensure that they are normalized so that they are comparable and guaranteed to match.

If these are more than simple comparable objects (e.g. instead of String or Date instances you are creating arrays complex Objects) then my library allows you to supply a comparison function so you can determine which are equal. See the library for more details on this.

Comment: and common retrieves a numbered value?

Comment: @DanielHanly No, `common` is then an array with all the values that are common to both arrays. You can use `common.length` to find out how many there may be.

Comment: @phogz Extending array.prototype like that will causes some compatibility issues if used in large chunks of code. I'd advice againts it.

Comment: @Raynos It will only cause compatibility issues in novice-level code that a) foolishly attempts to iterate arrays using `for...in` and b) when doing so foolishly does not us `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: excellent. And in answer to your question, there is a series of checkboxes for "available dates", then the checkbox value is stored "April 25th, April 26th" and so on.

Comment: @Phrogz Many people assume that the array prototype isn't changed and many people don't bother to test for hasOwnProperty on native objects. I do you hope you append those properties with the non-enumerable flag. There is no reason why you can't treat an array as an un-ordered set and use `for...in` on it

Comment: @Raynos, many people write buggy code, and many people are wrong for doing so. Not using `hasOwnProperty` is one such example.

Comment: @Raynos Of course there are a very few cases where it might be appropriate to iterate an array using `for...in` instead of a 'standard' `for` loop. And for these, you should use `hasOwnProperty`. No, as that code is 9 years old I'm not currently setting the non-enumerable flag. Thanks for pointing out that this is possible in very modern JS implementations; I had not seen that change.

Comment: @Box9 hasOwnProperty is only neccesary in a `for...in` loop if the object has properties which are not its own _and_ are enumerable. Writing a library that unexpectedly adds enumerable properties to native objects is asking for trouble. Corrupting native objects is just as bad as `undefined = true`

Comment: @Raynos For the [few modern browsers that support `Object.defineProperty`](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) I've updated the library to make the properties non-enumerable. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: @Phrogz I'm impressed that you made an improvement to a 9 year old library based on a passing comment. If you allow some kind of wrapper option like `set(array1).intersect(array2)` instead of extending prototypes I can imagine it easier to integrate into large existing code-bases. Whether it's worth your effort is another matter.

Comment: @Phorgz what a neat library for array operations! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If functional javascript is an option:

```
_.sum = function(array) {
    return _.reduce(array, function(memo, val) {
        return memo + val;
    }, 0);
};

var duplicates = _.intersect(valsA, valsB);
var fullPrice = _.sum(valsA.concat(valsB));
var reducedPrice = fullPrice - discountScalar * _.sum(duplicates);
```

Relies on [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) for easy cross browser implentation of functional methods. Most of these can be implemented with array.reduce & array.map on modern browsers.